# Mysql copy all rows from one table to another with specific columns and unix timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently copying all rows from Table1 to Table2 each day. Table2 is a 7 day archive of what Table1 contains each day. On average there are 150,000 rows to move over each day.

Table1

```
id | name | category | image | description | link
```

Table2

```
id | name | link | date
```

To do this I use PHP to select all rows in Table1:

`SELECT name, category, link FROM Table1`

Then I loop through each one and insert it into Table2:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 SET name = ''.$row["name"].'', link = ''.$row["link"].'', date = time()
```

`time()` is stored as an int(11) in the database. Can anybody advise if this is there is a better or more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Perhaps with one query called a [`INSERT SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)?

Comment: There are probably many different ways to do this, which one is "better" or "more efficient" is too broad to discuss in a Q&A site really. You'll likely just get varying opinions and not really know which one is "better". Also, it depends on other things going on in your application. What else are you selecting, inserting, at the same time or not, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just actioning this script and nothing else when rows are being copied over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO SELECT` rather than looping:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(name,link,date)
SELECT name, link, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() FROM Table1
```

Comment: Did a test and works perfectly, also very quick as well!